# Linux, Ksh script

Tags: linux, sendmail, ksh

I have a sendmail command in a `ksh` script which sends mail to users whenever the `ksh` script is called.

However from past few days its not working properly as the attachment is not being send instead I see garbled values in the mail body.

I tried to run the command alone through command line by replacing the variables with actual values and it is working absolutely fine.

Do not know why it is not working through ksh.

Command in ksh script :

```
(print "To: $MAILTO\nCc: $MAILCC\nSubject: $REPO Errors - FUNDRUNNER: Account Creation Report -FundRunner to AGCIS\nImportance: High\n"; \
                  print "Greetings,\n\nSee attached File for Errors.\n\n$countstr\n\nThanks,\nAGCIS IT"; \
                  print $HEADERSTR | cat - $FRFEEDFILEREPORT | uuencode fundrunner_feed_report_file.csv) \
          | sendmail -f$MAILFROM -t
```

Command after replacing the variables with actual values:

```
(print "To: poddarah\nCc: gayatra\nSubject: REPO_SVC_Dev8a: Errors - FUNDRUNNER: Account Creation Report -FundRunner to AGCIS\nImportance: High\n"; \
                  print "Greetings,\n\nSee attached File for Errors.\n\n`tail -1 /u/msim_dev/acd/informatica8/dev/TgtFiles/agcis_create_fundrunner_acct1 | sed 's/,/:/g'`\n\nThanks,\nAGCIS IT"; \
                  print Status,Message,Account ID,MSIM BU Client ID,Product Id | cat - /u/msim_dev/acd/informatica8/dev/TgtFiles/agcis_create_fundrunner_acct1 | uuencode fundrunner_feed_report_file.csv) \
          | sendmail -facdit -t
```

Error that I receive:

```
Greetings,

See attached File for Errors.

TOTAL:SUCCESS = 1424 FAILURE = 1157:::

Thanks,
AGCIS IT
begin 666 fundrunner_feed_report_file.csv
M4W1A='5S+$UE<W-A9V4L06-C;W5N="!)1"Q-4TE-($)5($-....
```

Please advise,

Reagrds,
Rahul Poddar

Comment: Are you referring to the last 2 lines of the output? That's the uuencoded file.

Comment: I know that but its working when I run it through command line.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Hi Alvits
The error is that the attachment is failing in the mail that we are receiving..

The Email body should read like:

Greetings,

See attached File for Errors.

TOTAL:SUCCESS = 1424 FAILURE = 1157:::

Thanks,
AGCIS IT

But some how when we are receiving the mail along with the body , garbled value is also getting appended and the attachment fails.

But somehow when the command used in the ksh script is run from command line by replacing the variables with actual values, we are receiving the correct format along with the attachment.

Comment: `sendmail` is not documented as having the ability to decide on its own to move a portion of the message body into an attachment. Programs like `mailx` can do this. Is it possible that, on the command line, `sendmail` is an alias for some other command?